# convert a parsed json to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi i have that php code like that example :

```
$array1 = array("fruits" => "banana","vegetables" => "tomatos");
$array2 = array("name" => "Jack","Age" => "32");

$array3 = array($array1, $array2);

echo json_encode($array3);
```

javascript code includes jquery :

```
   var json_data = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'scripts/myfile.php',
                data: { action: 'myaction' },
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {

                }
            });
           console.log(json_data );
```

this is the json_data content in browser's console:

```
"{"HUM":[{"label":"2014-10-16 17:08:55","y":"58"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:55","y":"56"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:50","y":"56"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:45","y":"56"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:40","y":"56"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:35","y":"56"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:30","y":"56"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:25","y":"56"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:20","y":"56"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:15","y":"56"},

"TEMP":[{"label":"2014-10-16 17:08:55","y":"26"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:55","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:50","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:45","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:40","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:35","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:30","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:25","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:20","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:15","y":"24"},

"HUM2":[{"label":"2014-10-16 17:08:55","y":"38"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:55","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:50","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:45","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:40","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:35","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:30","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:25","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:20","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:15","y":"36"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:10","y":"36"},

"TEMP2":[{"label":"2014-10-16 17:08:55","y":"23"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:55","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:50","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:45","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:40","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:35","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:30","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:25","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:20","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:15","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:10","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:05","y":"24"},{"label":"2014-10-15 08:16:00","y":"24"}]}"
```

now i want to convert it to array and then serparate it to arrays HUM - TEMP - HUM2 - TEMP2

Comment: var obj = JSON.parse(json_data);

Comment: Your arrays are not being terminated.  `JSON.parse()` will throw syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `result` variable which gets passed in to your AJAX call's `success` function:

```
success: function(result) {
    // result here is your JSON data which has already been parsed
}
```

You can access the individual arrays using either dot or bracket notation:

```
var HUM = result.HUM;
// or
var HUM = result["HUM"];
```

Comment: They've specified `dataType: 'json'`, which means jQuery will parse the server response as JSON anyway. Calling `JSON.parse` again is going to end badly.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist ah, I placed was passing in the wrong variable. Thanks for that!

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what I was trying to say. There's no reason to be calling `JSON.parse()` at all, with any variable (`json_data` isn't even JSON data, it's a jQuery Deferred). The response will already be an object, they just need to use `result` as an object, and access `result.HUM`, etc.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist it's Friday and almost the end of the day - that's a valid excuse for missing something obvious, right? :-) I've made one last amendment to my answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @AnthonyGrist is right already parsed but result.HUM worked when parsing inside success function is there any way to get that array from there by a global variable

Comment: @Souf yes, declare those variables outside of your AJAX call and assign them within the AJAX `success` call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create object from that json by using [`parseJson`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) method.

```
result = $.parseJson( result );
```

Now you will have all your arrays inside that object:

```
console.log( result['HUM'] );
console.log( result['TEMP'] );
// etc
```

Comment: isn't it just JSON.parse(string) ? This is the jQuery implementation, which is not native to js like this one is. Otherwise it'll work, though.

Comment: its parsed when  var json_data = $.ajax({ .... }); that variable takes parsejson(result) in jquery by default my question is how to convert that object to array

Comment: same result in console Object {HUM: Array[50], TEMP: Array[50], HUM2: Array[50], TEMP2: Array[50]}

Comment: What do you mean by convert object to array. What do you expect to have in final result?

Answer (score 0):

You need this method

```
JSON.parse(json_data);
```